# Running Artifactory on OpenJDK

Tags: artifactory

With the upcoming changes in [Oracle JDK support](https://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/java-se-support-roadmap.html) many people are switching to OpenJDK to run their Java programs.

More information about this can be found here: [Java is still free](https://medium.com/@javachampions/java-is-still-free-c02aef8c9e04).

When searching the documentation of Artifactory (5.x) about the [JDK system requirements](https://www.jfrog.com/confluence/display/RTF5X/System+Requirements), which hasn't been updated in a while (13/05/2018), it says:

> You must run Artifactory with JDK 8, preferably JDK 8 update 45 and above.
>
> Latest JDK. You can download the latest JDK from the [Oracle Java SE Download Site](https://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/downloads/jdk8-downloads-2133151.html).

I did not find information about running Artifactory on OpenJDK or JFrog's plans about which JDK versions they will support in the future.

The [last forum post](http://forums.jfrog.org/IMPORTANT-READ-THIS-BEFORE-REGISTERING-AND-REQUESTING-ACCESS-THIS-FORUM-IS-CLOSED-td7581183.html) points to Stackoverflow for community support, so I hope somebody from JFrog can shed some light on this issue (or update the official documentation).

thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I got in touch with somebody from JFrog, and I am posting the answer here in case anybody else is having the same question :

> Regarding your question, kindly note that Artifactory requires that *your_institution* must run Artifactory with JDK 8, preferably JDK 8 update 45 and above. Going forward, and with the change in the licensing structure by Oracle, *your_institution* needs to have either the ‘OpenJDK’ (i.e – the open source license) or the ‘OracleJDK’ (i.e. – the commercial license), at *your_institution*'s discretion and at its own expense (to the extent it chooses the OracleJDK).